# Prevent Google Drive from changing file attributes

Tags: google-drive

I've noticed that Google Drive for Windows changes file attributes on files that I place into it. It makes them hidden and system. How to prevent Google Drive from touching file attributes?

P.S. I don't use Windows Explorer for managing files (good old two panel file managers rule) and having hidden\system files display on is a mess.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are seeing this. I just checked my google drive folder and none of them are hidden or system files. I suspect that this may be inherited for some reason from a folder higher up.

Comment: Do you use Windows Explorer?

Comment: Yes. So the file browser that you are using is a potential culprit as well.

Comment: Dumb question: have you checked file properties for files in Google Drive folder?

Comment: "I just checked my google drive folder and none of them are hidden or system files" that meant the properties on the files.

Comment: Thanks, it seems update to the latest version of Google Drive fixes this.